# postgres complicated query

Tags: postgresql, select, subtraction

I wonder is it possible to make such query. The problem is that I have a table where are some numbers for date. 
Lets say I have 3 columns: Date, Value, Good/Bad

I.e:

```
2014-03-03 100 Good
2014-03-03 15 Bad
2014-03-04 120 Good
2014-03-04 10 Bad
```

And I want to select and subtract Good-Bad:

```
2014-03-03 85
2014-03-04 110
```

Is it possible? I am thinking a lot and don't have an idea yet. It would be rather simple if I had Good and Bad values in seperate tables.

Comment: Do you have exactly 2 rows, 1. Good & 2. Bad, for each date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to join your table back to it self as shown below. `myTable as A` will read only the `Good` rows and `myTable as B` will read only the `Bad` rows. Those rows then get joined into a signle row based on `date`.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ce81/1)

```
select 
a.date
,a.count as Good_count
,b.count as bad_count
,a.count-b.count as diff_count
from myTable as a
inner join myTable as b
on a.date = b.date and b.type = 'Bad'
where a.type = 'Good'
```

Output returned:

```
DATE                            GOOD_COUNT  BAD_COUNT   DIFF_COUNT
March, 03 2014 00:00:00+0000    100           15         85
March, 04 2014 00:00:00+0000    120           10         110
```

Another aproach would be to use `Group by` instead of the `inner join`:

```
select 
a.date
,sum(case when type = 'Good' then a.count else  0 end) as Good_count
,sum(case when type = 'Bad' then a.count else  0 end) as Bad_count
,sum(case when type = 'Good' then a.count else  0 end)  - 
    sum(case when type = 'Bad' then a.count else  0 end) as Diff_count
from myTable as a
group by a.date
order by a.date
```

Both approaches produce the same result.

Comment: Note: the first solution will fail for days for which *only* 'good' or *only* 'bad' observations exist.

Comment: I've finally tested your answer. The situation when 1 approach would fail shouldn't happen in my case and I've used it before you gave the second one:) It works exactly how it suppose to work. Thank you very much:)